# Communicating Between Digital Camera and Android Tablet

Tags: android, camera, connection, usb, tablet

I was wondering if there was a known camera that was compatible with android OS's. (such as the nexus 7).

I am trying to essentially control a high resolution digial camera from the android tablet so that it can control when to take a picture, and then retrieve the picture.

This would require a camera with a public API.

I have experience in android programming but not too much in communicating between two different devices. So i was wondering what I should look into in order to achieve this.

Comment: I very much doubt that there's any particular camera that's officially supported by Android as an external device.  That said, what you need is a camera whose API is published (or you can reverse engineer), an Android that's capable of going into host mode, and a fair amount of programming on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a camera that runs Android: http://news.yahoo.com/samsung-takes-aim-japanese-rivals-android-camera-034717081--finance.html
And since it is Android I guess that the API is public.

And the same camera with more info: http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/galaxy-camera/galaxy-camera/EK-GC100ZWABTU and it does run what look like standard android apps.

If you want to control that from another Android device, I think that would make a very interesting project.

The other possibility is the Nikon external control SDK, but I have no idea what language that is in. That was used to build the excellent Sofortbild app for Macs, which controls most Nikon DSLRs. https://sdk.nikonimaging.com/apply/

Comment: okay I definitely want to get the camera that runs android.
thanks.
I'm also unsure of how i would ultimately interact with it.
The android site shows how I can connect to a device using USB. But I'm still bewildered on how we could send and retrieve signals from it. It may not be as hard as I think but I'm making sure I understand everything before I go out and buy a camera.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html

Comment: I _think_ there is already a Samsung app that allows you to control this camera from a separate phone but the samsung website is so awful I can't be sure. I do think that you could write custom apps for it, and download them onto the camera just as we do with a phone. The app could connect to wifi to transfer the information to another custom app on a phone, or, even better, tablet. That's a nontrivial programming job but it sounds like fun. Ask Samsung? Except they don't seem to answer the questions in their Q&A section.

Answer (score 0):

There are Android applications which can control a set of cameras with added features. The one I'm using gives me the ability to take very specific timelapse shots which would be too complicated or even impossible to get through the camera's own controls. You can find many other control apps on the play store.

Unfortunately this one is only for Canon EOS cameras : [DSLR Controller](http://dslrcontroller.com)